# Am I supposed to use CanCan with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got devise working, but I see CanCan frequently mentioned in tutorials alongside Devise; is it meant to be complementary or is CanCan an alternative to Devise?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CanCan covers **authorization** - who is allowed to do what. Devise handles **authentication** - Are you truly you? That's how they complement each other. You can use one without the other.

See for example https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/identity-fundamentals/authentication-and-authorization.

Comment: Do not click on the link. It's no longer valid. Takes you to some bogus AI website

Comment: Thanks @ZairaZafar, I've replaced it with a more authoritative source.

Answer (score 1):

Devise handles authentication (logging in and out, handling sessions, etc..) but it does not handle authorization (allowing access to views or actions).

If you have a non-trivial application, then you will need authorization and probably roles.

CanCan is a very simple authorization Gem, which can work nicely if you have very few roles, and very simple authorization rules.   http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

If you have a lot of roles, or more complex authorization rules, then I would recommend declarative_authorization  http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

Both work very well with Devise, and either Rails 2 or Rails 3.

For implementing roles you have two choices: having a roles table and a join table between roles and users in your database; or using the role_model plugin http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association
You'll also have the choice if a user can only have one role, or many roles.

hope this helps